# Installing XGBoost GPU for R on Ubuntu AMI

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, gpu, xgboost

I'm on the AWS deeplearning Ubuntu AMI trying to install the XGboost GPU version R package using the instructions here: http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-with-gpu-support

I've cloned the repo, made a new build dir and then executed:

```
cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DR_LIB=ON
```

The error:

```
/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libblas.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas
/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libblas.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas
/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libblas.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find LibR (missing: LIBR_HOME LIBR_INCLUDE_DIRS LIBR_LIB_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindLibR.cmake:173 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:165 (find_package)
```

I believe this is due to the libblas.so.3 file living in /home/ubuntu/src/OpenBLAS instead of a more standard location. Just need a little nudge to bridge my lack of linux env variable knowledge and connect the two. Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm that your R installation is working? Also, look at the directories that contain your R packages by running `.libPaths()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create symbolic link from the expected location to the actual location of the shared library file or the directory which contains the expected shared library file to get around the problem.